filter pandas dataframe based on count of column value
I have a dataframe that looks like this -
import pandas as pd
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B"], data=[[1, "Red"], [2, "Blue"], [3, "Green"],
                                                   [4, "Red"], [5, "Blue"], [6,"Yellow"]])


   A       B
0  1     Red
1  2    Blue
2  3   Green
3  4     Red
4  5    Blue
5  6  Yellow

I want to filter this dataframe based on "count" of values in column "B". I want to get those rows where the value in column "B" occurs only once.
So I want to get the below dataframe
   A       B
2  3   Green
5  6  Yellow


Using .value_counts() == 1:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["A", "B"],
    data=[
        [1, "Red"],
        [2, "Blue"],
        [3, "Green"],
        [4, "Red"],
        [5, "Blue"],
        [6, "Yellow"],
    ],
)

print(df[df["B"].map(df["B"].value_counts() == 1)])

Output:
   A       B
2  3   Green
5  6  Yellow


You can use df.duplicated with keep=False to mark all duplicates as True and filter them out using the ~ operator (inverse) with boolean indexing:
sample_df[~sample_df['B'].duplicated(keep=False)]

   A       B
2  3   Green
5  6  Yellow


this solution works, but i think the one using value_counts() conveys the intention more clearly.
